# Adding ppa:deadsnakes/ppa via ssh on home server 18.04

Tags: apt, ppa

I decided to try my hand at some sys admin stuff so I put a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 on an old desktop computer to act as a server. That went well enough, but when I ssh to my "server" from my laptop and try to install tensorflow with gpu support using [this guide](http://www.python36.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-with-cuda-9-2-for-python-on-ubuntu) I run into some errors. After I run this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

I get the following error in my output:

```
W: GPG error: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F60F4B3D7FA2AF80
E: The repository 'http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release' is not signed.
```

However, when I add the repository locally on my laptop everything works as intended so I'm guessing there might be something wrong with my server.

Comment: Why are you trying to add a 16.04 repo to an 18.04 system? That's generally unwise.

Comment: Did my answer help? If not, please let me know.

Comment: @user535733 As far as I can tell deadsnakes is the repository for 18.04. What's really strange to me is that I can successfully add this repository on my laptop (also with a fresh install of 18.04), but get the error when running the same command on my other machine through ssh.

Comment: @StephanVierkant That seems to have fixed the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the guide Step 6: Install NVIDIA CUDA 9.2, this are the right instructions for Ubuntu 17.10 and Ubuntu 18.04 :

```
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1710/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
echo "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1710/x86_64 /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list
```